# Durandal and multiple views using the same vm

Tags: view, model, durandal

I have an ADD and an EDIT page for a customer entity.  The data to support each function is similar, however there are business rules that differ between the 2, and slightly different UI, so my original thinking is that I make 2 separate views, but use a single vm.  This is a different approach than the John Papa example I'm using as my guide, as he had a separate vm for each.    (sessionadd.js, sessiondetail.js).  The data is identical so it seems like a lot of duplication, but maybe that's the way to go.

Two questions:  what is the best practice in this scenario where the data for an add/edit is the same, but the rules are different?  I can already see myself doing "if (mode == 'add'){ // stuff } else {// its an edit }.  That bothers me a little, but I also don't like the idea of having to change 2 vms if I add a new field to the views.

Second question, can I specify the view as part of the route definition?  I didn't see anything in the docs but I'm still new to the framework. In the following routes, I would like the first one to be loaded with custedit.html and in the second one custadd.html.  Both using the custmaint.js vm (never at the same time tho).

```
{ route: 'custedit', moduleId: 'viewmodels/custmaint', title: 'Edit' },
{ route: 'custadd',  moduleId: 'viewmodels/custmaint', title: 'Add'  },
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the view you want to be used by defining getView() or viewUrl() on your viewmodel as described here:

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html

As to your initial question, if they are very similar, I would definitely combine edit and add operations within a single viewmodel **and** single view.   Sharing the same viewmodel but splitting the views will likely result in a ton of duplicated view code.   You could always decompose the elements of your view into smaller views if you need to simplify.

If the edit and add experience are different enough to warrant a separate view, I would create a separate viewmodel as well (and potentially look into splitting view parts and viewmodel functionality into smaller components)